# Why is synchronous communication more error prone than asynchronous in the context of Web Services?

Tags: web-services, asynchronous, message-queue, communication

On multiple occasions have I read that synchronous communication is more error prone than asynchronous, but there was never any reason provided. 
Why can more errors occur when using synchronous communcation? Wouldn't it be harder to reliably deliver messages to queues and persist them than to maintain a session? Or do they mean that it is easier to recover from errors when using asynchronous communication (e.g. by recovering messages/requests when errors occur)

Comment: Give a bit more context. What kind of communication are you talking about? Between processes? Between machines? Between people?

Comment: Yes, my question is a bit too general. I was talking about communication between web services. I will add this to my question